# Copy from Azure machine to Azure storage

Tags: azure, ansible, automation

What is the most sensible way to copy data from a VM on Azure to Azure storage.

To do things on my local PC I use azure-cli but this requires some setup steps (Azure Login).
I want to be able to spin up a VM using Ansible (done), build some stuff (done) and then save it to Azure storage.

Currently, the easiest way for me to do that is to download the data to my PC and then upload to Azure but this isn't practical or sensible.

My best option seems to be making sure Ansible/Azure is properly set up on the VM (this is non-trivial) so I can run the Ansible modules

Answer (score 1):

I would download and install a copy of [azcopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy) onto your target machine (I believe it is just an MSI install, so you can automate) and then use that to copy the information directly to Azure storage.  No need for Azure Powershell or CLI if you can pass the storage account names and keys in with your deployment/build process.

Not sure if you are using linux, but [azcopy for linux](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azcopy-on-linux-preview/) is currently in preview.